# Retrieve the home screen size (number of cells) in Android

Tags: android, android-widget, homescreen

Do you know if there is a way to programmatically, or by reading some pref file, retrieve the size of the home screen in Android (for example 4x4 on most phones, or 7x8 on most tablets).

There must be a xml file or db where this is stored, but I haven't been able to find which.

Answer (score 1):

The grid dimensions are handled by the launcher app, which may be AOSP, manufacturer (Sense, Blur, TouchWiz), or completely third-party (Nova, Launcher Pro, etc).  Any of these apps can store the dimensions in any way they choose (db, `SharedPreferences`, etc.), so you won't be able to find one specific place where that information is stored.  Sorry!

That's if you're looking for a generic solution.  If you have a special case here, with a rooted phone running a particular launcher app, then that info would probably be accessible via a file in the app's private data directory.